# Property does not exist on type object in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object while running i am getting the following error as Property doesn't exist on type object can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong in it.

```
let filter = {
      project: 'Test',
      flow: 'basic',
      start: 0,
      length: 3
    };
```

Error:

```
    src/app/_services/flow.service.ts(14,39): error TS2339: Property 'project' does not exist on type 'object'.
src/app/_services/flow.service.ts(14,62): error TS2339: Property 'flow' does not exist on type 'object'.
src/app/_services/flow.service.ts(14,83): error TS2339: Property 'start' does not exist on type 'object'.
src/app/_services/flow.service.ts(14,106): error TS2339: Property 'length' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Comment: what property..

Comment: Where do you see that error?

Comment: how do you use it? which property?

Comment: could you please share the error log

Comment: pleaseh share code snippet  flow.service.ts where you getting error

Comment: please post stackblitz @Nidhin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have `filter` typed as object[] as well. And property `project` does not exist on object. If you don't care about typing, you can declare `filter` as `Array<any>:`

`let filter: Array<any>;`

Answer (score 3):

Do this and the problem goes away,

```
private filter: any[];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be with your `flow.service.ts` field where you have set that to type `object` and all the field in filter don't exist on the type `object`. In your `flow.service.ts` change the feild type to any.

```
filter: any;
```

Answer (score -2):

Initialize an object with name filter like:

```
filter = [];
```